# Why do Downloaded Google Maps expire after 29 days?

Tags: google, gps, google-maps

I am assuming when the map expires, that I am SOL if I try to use it.

Within the Google Maps app, one can download maps for offline use: great when traveling abroad, especially when there is no connectivity.  What is the reason for having the maps expire after such a short time span?  Is there a way to increase the number?  It's odd in the sense expiration is 29 days and not a round number.

Comment: When the map "expires" does it remain in the cache? Or does expiring cause it to be cleared from the cache?   It seems like Google would let you keep using the map beyond expiration if there was no data source.   Expiring should just be a flag that says it would be better to get a new map, and not a cache clearing event.

Comment: @Tyson It's removed from the cache after 30 days. gatorback: It's actually 30 days, not 29, though it may start counting at 30d:0h:0m:0s and therefore almost immediately change to 29. As far as why, they don't want people downloading it and expecting the data to be valid for any extended period of time, as changes are constantly being made to update the maps.

Comment: I think it's related to copyright of map data. All data are not owned by Google. Data providers, given the right to Google to use it in a limited span of time (but may be more than 30 days)

Answer (score 2):

There hasn't been any info from Google as to why the maps expire in 30 days.

A theory postulated in [this Android SE site](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/143445) states

> ...I'd say it's highly likely that this time limit is related to contractual limitations at least in some areas. Kindof like how iTunes rentals expire, or Spotify Premium offline playlists expire: if there was no expiry date at all, then there's no difference between 'accessing' and effectively 'permanently buying for free/cheap'.

I also guess that Google wants to refresh the business list in the downloaded map data.  They charge businesses to advertise (not appear) in Maps and so they have an interest in keeping the downloaded data 'fresh'. <-- my $0.02